# Do I have to use "the" with "fortune" and "luck"

Tags: definite-article

I want to say "(the) fortune in my pocket" and "(the) luck in my pocket".

Do I need to put "the" there and is it at all acceptable here?

Comment: It would improve the question to include some detail about how these phrases will be used.

Comment: It is always important to give context. No one would simply say, "(the) fortune in my pocket" outside of a conversation. The nature of the conversation will determine the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "the" if you want it to be a "specific" fortune you want to describe and if you want to convey the general idea of luck or fortune it best suits if it is without "the".